# Access Violation Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework-6, access-violation

I am writing a WPF C# application and I'm using entity framework 6.0. I use LINQ to run a query on a remote database and it returns an IQueryable. When I try to iterate over the return, the program crashes even in debug mode. For some reason, the debugger cannot catch it. 
This is the code that is throwing the error:

```
var schedules = context.Schedules.Where(s => s.Username == username);
                foreach (var schedule in schedules)
```

The output window shows:

```
The thread 0x4174 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6128] EniproTutors.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

What could the problem be with the code?

Comment: Is 'schedules' returning a null?  Is context null?

Comment: Any unsafe code? An AV is only possible with unsafe code or with a CLR bug.

Comment: @jdweng no, schedules isn't null or empty

Comment: @usr Only managed code, no unmanaged blocks

Comment: Create an executable program that demonstrates the issue. I don't think it's possible to resolve this otherwise. You can then use that program to report the bug.

Comment: Try a ToList() after the where clause?

Comment: @BillReiss I tried that. And the program crashed at that line

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to work around it. The good thing I had going for me was that the table Schedules was empty, so I created another table with the same schema, added it to the model and removed the schedules table. It stopped crashing after that